# VBA Print and Write command confusion

Tags: vba, printing

In cell C18 of my code is the filepath

```
C:\blahblahblah\yay.db
```

I want to write a txt file so the first line reads:

```
uil_file_new.go( "C:\blahblahblah\yay.db","C:\blahblahblah\yay.db")
```

I have tried the following:

```
Dim template As String
template = Range("C18").Value

Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "test.txt") For Output Access Write Shared as #1
Print #1, "uil_file_new.go( " & template & "," & template & ")"
Close #1
```

which gives

```
uil_file_new.go( C:\blahblahblah\yay.db ,C:\blahblahblah\yay.db)
```

I need the txt file to have the " " around the filepaths. Is there is a way to pass a variable to a txt file but have the " " around what the variable contains?

I have tried the Write #1, command but it just puts "template", which isn't what I want.

It won't let me write single ", for example this would be ok:

```
Write #1, "
Print #1, template
Write #1, "
```

but it always corrects it to

```
Write #1, ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print a `"` double them up to `""` so;

```
Print #1, "uil_file_new.go(""" & template & """,""" & template & """)"
```